# Curve length of cycloid and Helix $\gamma(t) = r \begin{pmatrix} r \cos t \\ r \sin t \\ ht \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: analysis, curves, cycloid

I have to calculate the curve length of the

**(a)** $ \text{ cycloids } \gamma:[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R^2}$

$$\gamma(t) = r \begin{pmatrix} t-\sin t \\ 1 - \cos t \end{pmatrix}$$

**(b)** $\text{Helix } \gamma:[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3$

$$\gamma(t) = r \begin{pmatrix} r \cos t \\ r \sin t \\ ht \end{pmatrix}$$

Regarding **(a)** I have that

$$||\gamma'(t)|| = \sqrt{(1-\cos (t))^2+ (\sin(t))^2} = \sqrt{1-2\cos(t)+\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)} =\sqrt{2-2\cos(2 \cdot \frac{t}{2})}$$
$$= \sqrt{2} \sqrt{1- \cos^2(\frac{t}{2})+ \sin^2(\frac{t}{2})} = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{2 \sin^2 \frac{t}{2}} = 2|\sin (\frac{t}{2})|$$

$$L = \int_{0}^{2\pi}  ||\gamma'(t)||dt = 2 \int_0^{2\pi}|\sin(\frac{t}{2})|dt = 8 $$
Is that correct?

Regarding **(b)** I don't know how it's done because the $ht$ confuses me. Can someone show me how it's done?

Comment: $\dot{(ht)}=h$, simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h$ is a constant, same as $r$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t} &=& -r\sin t \\
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} &=& -r\cos t \\
\frac{{\rm d}z}{{\rm d}t} &=& h
\end{eqnarray}

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
L &=& \int_0^{2\pi} ||\gamma'(t)||{\rm d}t \\
&=& \int_0^{2\pi} \left[r^2\sin^2 t + r^2\cos^2 t + h^2 \right]^{1/2}{\rm d}t \\
&=& \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^2 + h^2}{\rm d}t \\
&=& 2\pi \sqrt{r^2 + h^2}
\end{eqnarray}